# Visual Studio 2013 C++ text format for classes

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2013

Today I adjusted my text formatting / programming style a bit and went through all the options in the text formatting option for the editor.

There are some limitations for the format and I accepted most of them except one for classes, access specifier (here not indented):

```
class MyClass
{
public:
    MyClass();
}
```

(And here indented):

```
class MyClass
{
    public:
    MyClass();
}
```

However I would like to make it this way (because it looks cleaner imo):

```
class MyClass
{
    public:
        MyClass();
}
```

Is there any way to do this with the formatting options? (Maybe I just missed something)

The annoying thing is, when reusing existing classes, they get formatted automatically in the wrong way when pasting them and I have to manually space them again. Also if the 2nd option (indented) is enabled, I can't use the tab key after an access specifier, because of the option that it automatically formats the code when pressing tab and I don't want to disable this option.

Until today I manually fixed it, but it would be really helpful for me if there is a better way of doing that, maybe if I can disable formatting just inside classes or something else, thanks.

Comment: `"when reusing existing classes, they get formatted automatically in the wrong way when pasting them and I have to manually space them again."` You can both turn this off in the options or you can just press "Ctrl+Z" to undo the auto-formatting after pasting without undoing the pasting.

Comment: Yes thats true, thanks for the answer, but the problem with "Ctrl+Z" is that all other formatations of the code also don't take place and turning it off in the options does no formatting at all.